# Sending an http request from an https website

Tags: node.js, http, https, lamp, amazon-lightsail

I have an https website (using LAMP stack) and I want to send an http request to port 3000 of a separate node.js server when you click a button (using an AJAX call and jsonp). It worked when my website was not secured (http), but after I switched to using a load balancer to make it secure (I'm using Amazon Lightsail), the http request no longer works. Is this because an https website does not allow http requests since all information on the website is supposed to be secure? And if so, should I send an https request instead? This would require me to make the node.js server https-secured by adding it to the load balancer. However, would this prevent me from requesting to port 3000 since load balancers only accept requests to ports 80 (http) and 443 (https)? I've looked into listeners but it seems like Amazon Lightsail does not support listeners with its load balancers.

Comment: You are correct.  Browsers don't want an https page using http because it tarnishes the security promise that the https page implies.  So, yes you should make your node.js server an https server and use https to contact it from your https page.

Answer (score 1):

Put that node server behind the same load balancer as a reverse proxy with another route or dns and it will probably work for you.